# htaccess Rewrite rule picking up subdomain when it should not

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've recently switched hosts, and was using the below rule to force www. for the root site in /public_html/

```
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.rootdomain\.com$
# RewriteRule (.*) http://www.rootdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It worked fine, despite the fact that I had:

```
public_html/otherdomain.com (has it's own htaccess)
public_html/otherdomain2.com (doesn't have it's own htaccess)
```

In the new host, I have the same setup with my add on domains. When I go to:

otherdomain.com - it works fine.

When I go to:

otherdomain2.com it redirects to rootdomain.com/otherdomain2.com

Trial and error shows it's the rewrite rule above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid matching subdomain use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rootdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```